# how to automatically load child table in jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

```
            Phones: {
                title: '',
                width: '5%',
                sorting: false,
                edit: false,
                create: false,
                display: function (studentData) {

   var $img = $('<img src="/Content/images/Misc/phone.png" title="Edit phone numbers" />');
                    //Open child table when user clicks the image
                    $img.click(function () {
                        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('openChildTable',
                                $img.closest('tr'),
                                {
                                    title: studentData.record.Name + ' - Phone numbers',
                                    actions: {
        listAction: '/Demo/PhoneList?StudentId=' + studentData.record.StudentId
                                    },
                                    fields: {
                                        StudentId: {
                                            type: 'hidden',
                                            defaultValue: studentData.record.StudentId
                                        },
                                        PhoneId: {
                                            key: true,
                                            create: false,
                                            edit: false,
                                            list: false
                                        }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }, function (data) { //opened handler
                                    data.childTable.jtable('load');
                                });
                    });
                    //Return image to show on the person row
                    return $img;
                }
            }
```

For this jtable how can we load automatically without binding it to click event of $img
means when the parent table load how to load child table automatically .is it possible to do so , for it i thought of using trigger to click event . Please suggest any method

Comment: If you trigger the click event, your child row will open, that seems not to be your wishes. Anyway, there is not "autoload" as far as i know for this component

Comment: actually found a way of doing it , just need to replace .click() event with .show() event ....

Comment: All your child table will be visible in that case?

Comment: does .show actually load the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recordsLoaded or rowInserted events. I would use rowInserted, for a better UX, master table would show only one row and child table gets shown with the following code

```
rowInserted: function (event, data) {
    var row = data.row[0];
    $('#div').jtable('openChildTable',
        $(row), //Parent row
        {
            title: '',
            actions: {
                listAction: '...'
            },
            fields: {
                
            }
        }, function (data) { //opened handler
            data.childTable.jtable('load');
        });
}
```